# Modules are not importing inside render process in electron

Tags: javascript, python, electron

I Am trying to create run a python script and show the data in the HTML view.

```
const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')

alert('Hello')
```

I have written this code inside the render process. I have connected this js file with my HTML page

### Problem

The `alert` function is not getting executed, I suppose that python-shell is not getting imported, because it is running when I am deleting the import statement.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Perhaps the `alert()` is not running because the import throws an error

Comment: I am not getting any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to run a node package in a renderer process. By default Electron does not have node enable for renderer processes (browser windows).

You can enable it by modifying your BrowserWindow configuration.

```
new BrowserWindow({

  // your window configuration

  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
  }
});
```

Reference: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window

Please note this feature is not enabled by default for security reasons. I recommend reading the security documentation to see if access to node in the renderer process will be secure for your use case.

Security Reference: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security